# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Im getting an error in my C# project which is causing me a headache. The error is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'
to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<KST.ViewModels.Gallery>'.
```

Here's my LINQ querys:

```
//Get Single Picture
var PictureResults = (from m in DB.Media where m.MediaID == 450 select m).SingleOrDefault();

//Get Gallery Pictures and Gallery Title
var GalleryResults = from g in DB.Galleries
                     join m in DB.Media on g.GalleryID equals m.GalleryID into gm
                     where g.GalleryID == 100
                     select new { g.GalleryTitle, Media = gm };
```

Here's my  viewmodels.

```
public class GalleryViewModel
{
    public Media Media { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Gallery> Gallery { get; set; }
}

public class Gallery
{
    public string GalleryTitle { get; set; }
    public int MediaID { get; set; }
    public int GalleryID { get; set; }
    public string MediaGenre { get; set; }
    public string MediaTitle { get; set; }
    public string MediaDesc { get; set; }
}
```

The squigally line error occurs under GalleryResults:

```
//Create my viewmodel
var Model = new GalleryViewModel
{
    Media = PictureResults,
    Gallery = GalleryResults
};
```

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ufuk Hacıoğulları has posted an answer and deleted it a few minutes later. I think his answer was correct and his solution gets rid of the error message. So I'm posting it again:

**Ufuk Hacıoğulları's answer;**

You are projecting a sequence of anonymous type instead of `Gallery`. Just instantiate Gallery objects in your select statement and it should work.

```
var GalleryResults = from g in DB.Galleries
                     join m in DB.Media on g.GalleryID equals m.GalleryID into gm
                     where g.GalleryID == 100
                     select new Gallery { GalleryTitle = g.GalleryTitle, Media = gm };
```

Comment: Should new Gallery be = to my Gallery class from above?

Comment: Yes. From your deleted answer it looks as if you haven't imported the required namespace. So you need to provide the full class name: `select new KST.ViewModels.Gallery { GalleryTitle = g.GalleryTitle, Media = gm }`.