# Error on 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery' when joining 2 tables for a details view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, view, model

So i'm trying to get some information from 2 tables to show on a details page.
I used something simmilar on the list page, which works perfectly, but it fails on the details page which only shows one record.

But on the details page i get the following error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[WreckingBolz.Models.RaidViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WreckingBolz.Models.RaidViewModel'.
```

I am using the following code

```
var raids = from b in db.Raid
                    join c in db.Users on b.RaidUser equals c.UserID
                    where b.RaidId == RaidID
                    orderby b.RaidDate descending
                    select new RaidViewModel()
                    {
                        RaidID = b.RaidId,
                        RaidDate = b.RaidDate,
                        RaidName = b.RaidName,
                        RaidStatus = b.RaidStatus,
                        RaidType = b.RaidType,
                        UserName = c.UserName
                    };
```

And on the view page i am including the model in the following way:

```
@model WreckingBolz.Models.RaidViewModel
```

Note: I've been using the following as a reference

[Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129147/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryableanonymoustype1)

[Cannot implicitly convert type ‘System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>’ to ‘System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SubCateViewModel>’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550278/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryableanonymoustype1-to-sys)

Comment: Does your query return a single or more `RaidViewModel` objects?

Comment: Yes, and with that i immediately fixed it. Just needed a .single() at the end.